# Is there a point completing all of the available memories before assassinating your target?

Tags: assassins-creed

Is there any point in collecting all memories before going to kill main victim? Completing 2 memories is sufficient. I completed everything in the poor district in Damascus and Acre, and I just started with Jerusalem and the missions are always identical. Only the informant challenges are different.

I really like this game, but if everything will be same till end of the game it's kind of disapointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can recall, there isn't any advantage to completing all pre-assassination requirements, other than a sense of completion... The multiple option for approaching an assassination was present so that users can opt to complete their preferred types.

Your disappointment was shared by many critics on the game's release and the repetitiveness was a strong critical point at the time. You should know that the later games improved on the issue by providing better variety in missions.

Edit: There is one advantage to complete all available pre-assassination missions - you can get more heath blocks earlier, but once you reach the maximum amount of health blocks, there's not point doing more than the required amount of missions.

Comment: Thanks, so I will just run around the city and kill guards to slightly improved gameplay and add som fun. I'm really looking forward to play all other AC games.